# my text is going out of the cell

Tags: tables

I am having trouble formatting a wide table. Thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429289/5404) my basic structure seems fine. But I find now that the text in one of the columns is too wide for the cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,ragged2e,tabularx,geometry,amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{table}[htbp]

    \caption{Lots of vertical rules}  \label{tab:a}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{l|} *{3}{L|}}
        \hline
        Ref & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Model Used}
        & Approach & Limitation & Goal \\
        \hline
        & MBTI & FFM & BFI & KTS & BTR & NEO-FFI 
        & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} \\ 
        \hline
        [10] &  & &\checkmark & & & 
        & Interactive personality profiling approach 
        & Test were based on subjective evidences which may lead to uncertainty.
        & In order to propose a structure for effective software team structure. \\
        \hline

        [20] &  & & & & &\checkmark 
        & Quazi-Experiment 
        & This study is conducted with students which leads to ambiguity on difference in nature of students and software engineers.
        & In order to propose a structure for effective software team structure. \\
        \hline
        & & & & & & & & & \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that in the sell containing the text "Quazi-Experiment" the words are too long: they are sticking out past the right hand side of the cell. How can I prevent this?

Comment: this is the same question as your previous: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429286/my-table-is-going-out-of-the-page.

Comment: apart from it being a duplicate, when asking questions please always post a complete example, not just a fragment, here for example the text may or may not be overfull depending how wide the table is which depends on `\textwidth` which you have not shown.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but the text in my document is goint to the next cell. how can i resize my text in the cell.

Comment: @Zarko why is it a duplicate of _that_ question? the original q used `l` columns, mico's answer there said to use X columns, and this question is using X but is a followup that line breaking is not right (it is probably a duplicate of a different question)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, this question contain Mico answer from op previous question (which works.) regarding this, it is not duplicate. however, op ask for solving the same problem as in previous question (which is solved, however op had to consider preamble in Mico answer). now can be concluded, that is not clear what is the problem ...

Comment: Please tell us (a) which document class you employ, (b) which fonts and font size you employ, and (c) how wide the text block is.

Comment: I think he's using just the set-up that you gave in your previous answer @mico, plus amsfonts for `\checkmark`. His problem is simple: "Quazi-Experiment" (sic) is not hyphenating ... of course, so it is escaping from its cell. @Iftikhar: try making it "Quasi Experiment" (no hyphen) or "Quasi-Experi\-ment". TeX doesn't hyphenate words with explicit hyphens unless you tell it to.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for your valuable answers. the issue is solved but now the problem is i want to split this table to multiple pages as it is a long table.

Comment: @IftikharAhmad I have edited your original question to give you a model to follow. If you (a) post some COMPLETE code which can be compiled--as short as you can make it to show the problem, but compilable, and (b) be very specific in the question about exactly the problem you are having, you will likely find you get easier answers.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer provides additional code in the setup of the `L` column type, to permit hyphenation of long words that occur at the very beginning of a cell.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{%geometry,
    tabularx, % for 'tabularx' env.
    ragged2e, % for '\RaggedRight' macro
    booktabs, % '\toprule' '\midrule', etc. 
    amssymb}  % for '\checkmark' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default value: 6pt
\caption{Lots of vertical rules}  \label{tab:a}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |l| *{6}{c|} *{3}{L|} }
    \hline
    Ref & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Model Used}
    & Approach & Limitation & Goal \\
    \hline
    & MBTI & FFM & BFI & KTS & BTR & NEO- 
                    & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} \\
    & & & & & & FFI & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} \\
    \hline
    [10] & & & \checkmark & & &
    & Interactive personality profiling approach
    & Tests were based on subjective evidence, which may lead to uncertainty.
    & In order to propose a structure for effective software team structure. \\
    \hline
    [20] & & & & & & \checkmark
    & Quasi-\hspace{0pt}Experiment
    & This study is conducted with students which leads to ambiguity on difference in nature of students and software engineers.
    & In order to propose a structure for effective software team structure. \\
    \hline
    & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```